# How to remove vertical column borders from Jface Table viewer?

Tags: swt, jface

I want to remove the vertical column borders from Jface Tableviewer , is it possible to do? using setLinesVisible(false) horizontal lines disappeared but not vertical lines, how to achieve this?

Comment: Exactly what is drawn depends on the underlying native table control. On macOS setLinesVisible(false) does turn off the vertical lines, Windows and Linux may behave differently.

Comment: Is there any other way to remove vertical lines in windows?